# Postgres index has massively different impact on raw SQL vs ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, indexing, postgresql-9.4

I have a table with 150k names and tried adding an index to `lower(name)` to speed up lookups. The index speeds up raw SQL queries by about x100, but the same query performed using ActiveRecord is unaffected, if not a bit slower.

These are the queries:

```
NamedEntity.where("lower(name) = ?", "John Doe".downcase).first
```

vs

```
conn.execute(
  %q{SELECT "named_entities".* FROM "named_entities" WHERE (lower(name) = 'john doe');}
)
```

I added the index with

```
CREATE INDEX index_named_entities_on_lower_name ON named_entities USING btree (lower(name));
```

Here are the benchmarks comparing all cases (50 executions each):

```
no index,   AR:  6.999421
with index, AR:  7.264234
no index,   SQL: 5.569600
with index, SQL: 0.045464
```

The query plans are the exact same for AR and SQL.

Without index:

```
Seq Scan on named_entities  (cost=0.00..2854.31 rows=785 width=130)
  Filter: (lower((name)::text) = 'john doe'::text)
```

And with index:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on named_entities  (cost=9.30..982.51 rows=785 width=130)
  Recheck Cond: (lower((name)::text) = 'john doe'::text)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_named_entities_on_lower_name  (cost=0.00..9.26 rows=785 width=0)
        Index Cond: (lower((name)::text) = 'john doe'::text)
```

I have no idea how to explain this. The overhead added by ActiveRecord should not be influenced by the index, so the *difference* in speed between index and no index should be the same for AR and SQL, no?

Comment: did you cleared cache and reload everything after adding the index?

Comment: What caches can I clear here?

Comment: This is quite interesting. Maybe ActiveRecord dosen't see the index, because you created it directly by yourself on the db. Try to use `add_index` via a migration and add the index that way.

Comment: `add_index` doesn't support indices on expressions. And I need it to be case insensitive. Also, AR shouldn't need to know about the index, as it sends the same SQL to Postgres, whether that then uses an index or not.

Comment: The log should be showing you the queries executed and the time taken for execution. Anything to learn from that?

Comment: I got the raw SQL from the `#to_sql` method on the AR query, so that should be the same as what the logs show...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to fix the problem, by just adding `ANALYZE named_entities;` after creating the index. That makes Postgres update its statistics on all kinds of things, so it can generate a better query plan. (Also found out the [Postgres docs](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Introduction_to_VACUUM,_ANALYZE,_EXPLAIN,_and_COUNT#Using_ANALYZE_to_optimize_PostgreSQL_queries) are amazing.)

That still doesn't explain the time difference though, as the `explain`s indicated both the SQL and AR queries led to the same slow query plan.